# C# datagridview row select with CTRL and SHIFT

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I need to implement datagridview selection in that way so when user clicks a cell whole row is selected, when user holds CTRL key additional rows are selected, when user holds SHIFT key range of rows are selected. According to requirement I cannot show RowHeaders so selection should be based on cell clicking. I also know that `datagridview.SelectionMode = FullRowSelect` will do the trick but I'm getting one problem when using SHIFT for selection - gaps. When someone selects one row, then presses SHIFT and then jumps over few row to select anoter not all cells became selected(look at the picture - rows with x=3,4,5 have cells which are not selected).

[image]

Help me to solve this problem.

Actually I have some ideas. For example, somehow treat clicking on a cell as clicking on a rowheader, but I'm not sure how to implement this.

Comment: I've tried to replicate your problem with no success - fullrowselect with no row headers and multiselect true works fine for both CTRL and SHIFT selects. Is there any other unusual code that you haven't shown in your question?

Answer (score 1):

```
datagridview.SelectionMode = FullRowSelect
```

and

```
datagridview.RowHeaderVisible=false
```